# Display an object programmatically placed behind an object placed by storyboard in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

How can I display an object that I have programmatically placed behind an object that has been placed on the stroyboard? The default is for objects that are programmatically placed to be on top, but was curious on how to change that.

Comment: Look at the `sendSubviewToBack:` and `bringSubviewToFront:` methods of `UIView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add subview below,use this function

```
[self.view insertSubview: belowSubview:];
```

Or add subview first then

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [sendSubviewToBack:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sendSubviewToBack:).

Also take a look at [exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:)